# Подключение CSS и JS библиотек в Андроид приложение

Tags: java, android, html, webview

Делаю приложение в Android Studio и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Все приложение это `WebView` и отображаю там `html` файл из `assets`.

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Только теперь не понимаю как подключить `css и js файлы`. Нужно что-то добавлять в код программы или изменить пути в самом `html` файле?

Answer (score 0):

Положите свои CSS и JS либы туда же в assets, сделайте ссылку на них в HTML и загружайте через:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset",content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

В этом случае загрузчик будет использовать локацию `file:///android_asset` как базовый URL и относительно его загружать указанные в HTML CSS/JS файлы.

Ссылка в hmtl должна быть относительной, типа:

```
<LINK href="./mycss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Я кажется разобрался. Почему-то в скриптах не работает let. Заменил на var и стало все ок. Но это же не практично. Есть фикс?

Answer (score 0):

Создаете теку raw, переносите туда файлы и объявляите их:

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

потом дайте ссылку на файлы

```
       webView.loadUrl("file:///raw/work.js");
```

или

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/work.js");
```

Comment: а что такое «тека raw»?

Comment: Raw там всякие файлы хранятся. Музыка в основном, @aleksandrbarakin